# Unable to login with google after publish on Play store

Tags: react-native, google-play, google-signin, google-api-client

I published an app on play store. There is an option to login with google in this app. When I create a build in apk file with release signing key and install is in my real android device then I can logged in with google but when I publish same build with same SHA-1 certificate fingerprint on play store then it's not working.
Please help me to fix this issue.
 
Thank you

I tried by changing the SHA-1 certificate fingerprint but not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using firebase, this is what worked for me

Open app in play console -> Setup -> App Signing -> under App signing key certificate, copy SHA-1 certificate and add it in to your firebase SHA certificates
I added the certificate, do not remove previous ones